# How to check state parameter in React base component

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use React and TypeScript.

I prepared BaseComponent class witch is base class for all my react components

```
class BaseComponent<P, S> extends React.PureComponent<P, S> {
   public renderReactLoadScreen() {
      return(
      this.state.isLoading &&  <LoadScreen />
      )
   }
}
```

I want to use it like this:

```
class Register extends BaseComponent<LoginProps, any>{
   ...
   public render() {
      return(
        <React.Fragment>
            {super.renderLoadScreen()}
            ...
        </React.Fragment>
      )
   }
}
```

But I get error:

```
Property 'isLoading' does not exist on type 'Readonly<S>
```

Comment: Ok, I find something `interface IState { isLoading: boolean; } class BaseComponent<P> extends React.PureComponent<P, IState>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please notice that you should specify the type of state for e.g:

```
interface SampleState {
    isLoading: boolean;
}

class Register extends BaseComponent<LoginProps, SampleState>{
   ...
}
```